# How to start multiple animations at once in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

## Goal:

- To start multiple animations all at once.

---

### Expected Result:

- All animation defined and started at once must run parallel.

---

### Actual Result:

- The only animation that has been started first shows, the below animations doesn't even start.

---

### The Code for Reference:

```
class KivySplash(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivySplash, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim1 = MyAnimation(duration=4, opacity=0)
        anim1.bind(on_complete=self.on_anim1_complete)
        self.animation = MyAnimation(duration=3) + MyAnimation(duration=4, opacity=1) + MyAnimation(duration=5) + anim1
        self.img1 = Image(source=os.path.join(original_dir, "Kivy-logo-black-512.png"), opacity=0)
        self.img2 = Image(source=os.path.join(original_dir, "python-powered-w-200x80.png"))
        self.label1 = Label(text="Powered by:", font_size=48)
        box_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        box_layout1 = BoxLayout()
        box_layout.add_widget(self.label1)
        box_layout1.add_widget(self.img1)
        box_layout1.add_widget(self.img2)
        box_layout.add_widget(box_layout1)
        self.add_widget(box_layout)

    def on_anim1_complete(self, *args):
        do_nothing(self, *args)
        if self.img1 in self.animation.animated_widgets:
            pass

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.animation.start(self.img1)
        self.animation.start(self.img2)
```

---

#### Thanking You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have encountered a bug in the kivy `Animation`. If you are just using a simple `Animation`, then starting that `Animation` on multiple `Widgets` should work fine. The bug happens when you are using a `Sequence` (`Animations` connected with '+'). `Sequences` work by running the first `Animation` and binding an internal `on_complete` method that starts the next `Animation` in the `Sequence`. When you call `start`, that `on_complete` method is bound. But as soon as the first `Animation` on the first `Widget` in the `Sequence` completes, the second `Animation` is started and the `on_complete` method is unbound. Now, when the first `Animation` on the second `Widget` completes, the `on_complete` is not called (is was unbound after the first `Widget` completed), and the second `Animation` is not started.

Here is the code from `Sequence`:

```
def on_anim1_complete(self, instance, widget):
    self.anim1.unbind(on_complete=self.on_anim1_complete)
    self.anim2.start(widget)
```

In your case, it looks like the `Animation` is not starting on the second `Widget`, but because your first `Animation` doesn't actually animate anything, you don't see it.

Unfortunately, there are not many alternatives to avoid this problem.

- You can build a copy of the entire `Animation` a second time (`copy()` or `deepcopy()` will not work), and just use two different animations (one for each `Widget`).
- You can do your own sequencing by just using simple `Animations` and use your own `on_complete` to start the next `Animation`. Conveniently, the `on_complete` arguments includes the animated widget that you need for the next `start()` call.
- In some situations, you may be able to animate a single container (like a `Layout`). Since that is only animating a single `Widget`, the sequencing should work correctly.